# approach to pass additional parameter in post URL

Tags: theme-development, core

I am trying to automatically pass an additional parameter whenever the post is saved as Draft or Published.

When a post is saved as Draft or Published, the URL is updated to /wp-admin/post.php?post=postid

I want to add additional parameter in post URL on click publish so the URL becomes /wp-admin/post.php?post=postid&new_param=postid

My approach so far: wp-includes/post.php

```
    '_edit_link'            => 'post.php?post=%d'
```

I added the additional parameter and it worked fine but I need the additional parameter to have post id too i.e post=123&new_parameter=123&new_para=true

where 123 is postid

but I can't seem to figure out how to properly pass the postID for the other parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m not clear on where you want to “pass” it and what effect it’s going to have. Can you elaborate so that it’s clearer what you’re trying to do?

Comment: My bad! I want to pass it in the WP Edit post URL. So when a post is published or saved as a draft, the additional parameter is included automatically.